# formatting string outputs in python

Tags: python, string, list, join

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]


1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 7
1 2 3 4 6 7
1 2 3 5 6 7
1 2 4 5 6 7
1 3 4 5 6 7
2 3 4 5 6 7
```

i created a program and i'm trying to get my output in a string format instead of a list. i think the join delimiter will work for me in this case, however i don't know where and how to implement it in this case. the second set of output is the one i want.

Comment: This seems trivial. What have you tried?

Comment: Quite trivial indeed. The answers here seem to have covered it. One printing, one generating a string with newline separators in between. Can't think of anything else to do.

Answer (score 4):

Given

```
data = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7],
    [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7],
    [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    ]
```

This

```
for row in data:
    # apply str to each item in row using map.  join result with space.
    print ' '.join(map(str, row))
```

ouputs

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 7
1 2 3 4 6 7
1 2 3 5 6 7
1 2 4 5 6 7
1 3 4 5 6 7
2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your code looks like this:

```
my_list=[ [ '1', '2', '3'],
  [ '1', '2', '3'],
  [ '1', '2', '3'] ]
```

This should produce your desired output:

```
'\n'.join(''.join(line) for line in my_list)
```

If your elements are anything but string-likes, you need to convert them, too:

```
'\n'.join(''.join(str(element) for element in line) for line in my_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Join is a String function

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
print ' '.join(map(str,l))
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Join the inner list with `' '` and the outer with `'\n'`:

```
In [125]: l
Out[125]: 
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7],
 [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7],
 [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]

In [126]: print '\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, i)) for i in l )
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 7
1 2 3 4 6 7
1 2 3 5 6 7
1 2 4 5 6 7
1 3 4 5 6 7
2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: Note that his/her data is several lists, not a list of lists.

Comment: That may be a misunderstanding. It seems to me the OP was merely discussing two different possible output formats.

Answer (score 1):

Much depends on the range of values you might expect to encounter. Other solutions work well with the posted data, but would fail to align everything should two-digit values also be included, since then the string representations of the numbers are of variable width.

In such a case one could generate a format string to ensure correct alignment, and when dealing with numeric values this is often preferable to misalignments which can make it difficult for the human reader to easily associate all the values of a column.

Presuming all rows of data to be the same length the following code is a suitable model.

```
data = [
    [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [1, 22, 3, 4, 5, 7],
    [1, 2, 33, 4, 6, 7],
    [1, 2, 3, 55, 6, 7],
    [1, 2, 4, 5, 66, 7],
    [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 77],
    [22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77],
    ]

rowlen = len(data[0])
item_format = "{:5d}"
format_string = " ".join(rowlen*[item_format])

for row in data:
    print format_string.format(*row)
```

The output is

```
11     2     3     4     5     6
 1    22     3     4     5     7
 1     2    33     4     6     7
 1     2     3    55     6     7
 1     2     4     5    66     7
 1     3     4     5     6    77
22    33    44    55    66    77
```